# Salt state execution order

Tags: salt-stack

My top file looks like this.

`base:
  'G@roles:docker':
    - states/docker
  'G@roles:sb-monolith-ecr':
    - states/aws-ecr-logged-in
    - states/sb-monolith-ecr
  'G@roles:web-applications-ecr':
    - states/aws-ecr-logged-in
    - states/web-applications-ecr`

The aws-ecr-loggin-in state:

`aws-erc-logged-in:
  cmd.run:
    - name: $(aws ecr get-login --region={{ pillar['aws']['region'] }})`

I am expecting the login state to trigger once and before the states that require the authentication to AWS ECR. Today when I refreshed my minions some of them had authentication errors. What is the best way to ensure the login command is run at the right time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be better if you used [`require`](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/requisites.html#require) to ensure that you logged in before any other state that needs authentication. also if there is an error in the login command any state that depends on it wont executed which will save you from getting authentication errors in this case.
In your case you will need to require an SLS which called `aws-ecr-logged-in`
What do you think ?

Comment: I had the setup before, however the login triggers twice within this approach. Is there any to make the command a execute "once per machine per state update" concept ?

Comment: what about writing an sls that require sls: login, then including sb-monolith-ecr if the role is sb-monolith-ecr and including web-applications-ecr if the role is web-applications-ecr (use if statement provided by jinja). do you have something in mind ?

Comment: That sounds like it would work. I'll try it out when I have some time.